# Autoit getting the name of a control

Tags: vb6, controls, autoit

I have a VB6 control (VSFlexGrid) that I would like to get the name of. I have a class and id to reference it by and I am able to focus it but I don't know how I am suppose to retrieve the name of the control. How would I do this in Autoit?

Comment: What does it have to do with [tag:vb6]?

Comment: It is a VB6 control that I am attempting to get the name of.

Comment: If by "name of a control" you mean its name as in VB6 code, then it's not exposed to the outer world. If you mean something else, please explain your goal in more detail.

Comment: I think it would help anyone out who's trying to help you if you post your code. Are you talking about how to get the ControlID?

Answer (score -1):

in form design mode the grid is given a name in the property window.

you can reference it by the Name given in code.

so select the grid in the form design view and press F4 - the (name) property will be something like VSFlexGrid1 or maybe myGrid or some such..

In code you can refer to it as VSFlexGrid1.Position or VSFlexGrid1.Rows or whatever of it's properties you need to work with.

You can do more exotic things like looping through the form controls collection and detecting if it is a VSFlexGrid type, but that may be more than you are looking for.

Comment: Have you noticed "How would I do this in **Autoit**?" part of the question?